# How to use explicit member constraints with recursive types

Tags: f#, recursive-type

Is it possible to use explicit member constraints with recursive types?

The following works fine (not recursive):

```
type Wrapper< ^a when ^a : (static member Baz: string) > = Wrapper of ^a

type Foo =
  { Str: string }
  static member Baz = ""

type Bar =
  { Foo: Wrapper<Foo> }
  static member Baz = ""
```

The problem is that I also need a field on `Foo` of type `Wrapper<Bar>`. But once I change `type Bar` to `and Bar` in order to enable this (or make the whole module recursive), I get the following error:

```
type Wrapper< ^a when ^a : (static member Baz: string) > = Wrapper of ^a

type Foo =
  { Str: string }
  static member Baz = ""

and Bar =
  { Foo: Wrapper<Foo> }
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^  The type 'Foo' does not support the operator 'get_Baz'
  static member Baz = ""
```

Is it possible to use explicit member constraints with recursive types?

Comment: cant' you use an interface?

Comment: Not in this case - I need to access a static member using only `^a`. Of course, there might be entirely different ways to solve things.